# CSS media query: max device width

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to hide a notice on devices whose max screen size is 1024. For all greater sizes the notice will be displayed. I use the following css code but it does not work. What I am doing wrong?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1024px)
{
  .global-site-notice
   {
   display: none !important;
   }
 }
```

Comment: max-width.  try to use this.

Comment: Check this one. https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/1eur854z/

Comment: I am testing this  both on desktop browser and on mobile devices. I have also tried max-width. The website is the following: http://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/.

Comment: What device is this not working on? I see it working fine on Chrome, with max-width instead of max-device-width.

Comment: Do you have the meta viewport tag in your header?